# How to get a DateTime in a random string?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am given a bunch of strings that tell me about an event, and I need to convert all the strings into a start `DateTime` and an end `DateTime`. At first, I tried going character by character through the string, but it became too complicated when strings had multiple dates in them. I've also tried to parse many date formats, but when the days and months come first, then the times, it doesn't work. I am working with C#, and have also tried searching through strings using Regex but I'm having trouble with that because I can't match the day to the right time.

Here's a few examples of the strings I'm given:

> September 12-13,2015, Saturday 10:30 a.m.-6p.m. Sunday 10 a.m. noon

Should have 2 dates:

```
StartDate: 2015/09/12 10:30 EndDate: 2015/09/12 18:00
StartDate: 2015/09/13 10:00 EndDate: 2015/09/13 12:00
```

> June 3 - September 9, 2015, Tuesday-Thursday 6-7 p.m. , Sunday 10-11 a.m

Multiple dates Tuesday/Thursday/Sunday with date range:

```
StartDate: 2015/06/04 18:00 EndDate: 2015/06/04 19:00
StartDate: 2015/06/07 10:00 EndDate: 2015/06/07 11:00
StartDate: 2015/06/09 18:00 EndDate: 2015/06/09 19:00
StartDate: 2015/06/11 18:00 EndDate: 2015/06/11 19:00
```

...continues following same pattern

Thank you.

Comment: seems like a job for tokens... first try to generalize the possible formats into rules.

Comment: Try if one of the standard date-time parsing modules work for you. For example, Perl has some: http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm  If not, another option is to design a small DSL (domain specific language) with the possible date formats and use a parser generator like ANTLR or Flex/Bison to generate code.

Comment: What would the possible date formats be when they are so varied? There are strings that start with time, and end with month, and so forth.

Comment: Why does the first string `"Sunday 10 a.m. noon"` have an end time of `12:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach to this:

1) Scanning/Lexing -> Scan for basic tokens.

```
Names: September, Saturday, AM, etc.
Numbers: 12, 2015, 9, etc.
Operators serving as Separators: '-', ',', space, etc.
   '-' acts as a range operator as in FromDate - ToDate.
   ',' and space separate components of a date
```

2) Parsing -> Build a parse tree out of tokens.

```
Names are classified into Months, days of week, etc.
Numbers are identified as year, month or day if it 
can be done unambiguously. Otherwise, their identification 
is left to later steps.
We can use some heuristics, like day of month almost always follows month.
```

3) Now, Parse tree represents date-time entries separated by '-'.

```
At this point, a date in the tree can be partial or complete.
Introduce separator when it is missing between adjacent dates or times.
"Sunday 10a.m noon" is missing separator between '10am' and 'noon'
```

4) Identify complete and partial dates from parse tree.

```
For example, "September 9, 2015" is a complete date, while "June 3"
is incomplete. After extracting at least one complete date, infer 
the missing elements in incomplete dates from surrounding context.
"June 3" is incomplete because of missing year, so we grab the 
year from the nearest complete date as 2015.
```

5) If a complete date can't be found in the above step,

```
Use two adjacent dates and let them fill in missing parts
from each other to arrive at a complete one. "September 12 - 13, 2015" 
is one such example. Left side of the separator is missing 
year and can get it from right side. Figure out the date for 
a day of week, like Thursday from the complete date in the string
```

Comment: Just curious, Could you describe the high level design of the solution implemented for this issue?